# I setup vsftpd on ubuntu server on my ec2 instance, how to connect using SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp, amazon-ec2

I connect to my ec2 instance using ssh so I don't have to login each time.

I just installed vsftpd on the ubuntu server, but when I connect it obviously asks for my username and password.

Since I connect using the ubuntu user that my AMI comes with, I don't even know the root password.

Is there a way I can login via ftp using SSH?

Or do I just create a user on the system for ftp purposes?

I've locked ftp to my IP address, and I will shutdown the ftp service once I'm done as I dont need it running 99.99999% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not comfortable with command line `scp` then you could use a client like [**filezilla**](http://filezilla-project.org/) configured in it's server manager dialogue to connect to `Server Type: SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol`

You may have to enable the sftp server on your AMI. Check that the line

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

is not commented out with a # in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 2):

No. SSH and FTP are different protocols.

If you have SSH running then just use `scp` or `rsync` to copy files over, no FTP needed.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to set up password for your ubuntu server ec2 instance. If your username is 'ubuntu' you can create a password for it using

`sudo passwd ubuntu`

You can then try connecting to EC2 instance using FTP with the username and password.

If i'm right, you'll have to set filezilla or your FTP client to active mode ( from preferences ) to connect to EC2 instance.

If you havent configured your FTP server in EC2 Ubuntu instance, here is a guide to do that 
http://quadloops.com/installing-up-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server-12-04/